# Generate a 'natural' path through a set of 3D points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set $P=\{p_0,\ldots,p_n\}$ of 3D points, such that a curve (spline) passes through each point in order. The curve is well-defined (in this case a cubic spline) and for each point $p_i$ I have a tangent $T_i$.

For $p_0$ I have, besides $T_0$, also $N_0$ and $B_0$, 3 mutually orthogonal axes which define a 3D orientation.

What I need is to a way to generate a 'natural 'or 'least torque' way to calculate $N$ & $B$ along the curve, so that at any point I have a local coordinate space. To qualify 'natural', imagine  pushing a flexible, frictionless hose over a steel rod bent into the shape of the curve.

I do *not* need a mathematically exact solution, in fact probably calculating $N_i$ & $B_i$ only might be sufficient since $T$ *is* mathematically defined along the curve.

Note, this is different from [more common ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) to generate a moving coordinate system along a curve; in those kind of approaches an 'S' shape means the coordinate system will rotate 180 degrees. Clearly, we have to 'walk' along the curve rather than calculating $B/N$ purely based on $T$ and its derivatives in this case.

Comment: Best of luck with your 'natural path'.

Comment: ((John asked a similar question on stackoverflow a couple of days ago I noted)). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907536/generating-a-natural-path-along-a-spline

Comment: Indeed: but that took a turn down Frenet frames (see my other Q: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103924/generating-orthogonal-axes-on-a-spline), and that is a solution to a different problem.